# Background image not covering and text vertically aligned to the bottom

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am struggling to understand how to achieve a couple of things. I have created a div with a background image, the background image is required to be responsive and cover the background area. the text needs to be vertically aligned to the bottom of the div also.

I will have four of these sat side by side all 25% wide each.

I have created a demo of it and looking for some advice on th best way to approach this.

```
.img1{
        height: 400px;
        width: 25%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 40px 30px; 
        @include background-size(cover);
        text-align: center; 
        float: left;    
        background-size: cover;
        background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Most_beautiful_landscape_wallpaper.jpg");
    }
```

[Demo of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/tLvgs0yz/)

Comment: For the `cover` problem, see my answer... To align the text vertically, what have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried to sue the vertical align properties, I have tried to position the text absolute but it needs to be responsive so that isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `background-size` after your `background` :

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tLvgs0yz/1/)**

```
background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Most_beautiful_landscape_wallpaper.jpg");
background-size: cover;
```

Note : you can add `center center` in your background declaration for better results.

To align vertically, you can use this trick : add a `:before` on the container and make it `display: inline-block` with the `h2`. Then just use `vertical-align: bottom`

```
.img1 {
    font-size: 0; // make sure there is no space between inline-block elements
}
.img1:before {
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 24px; // set the font size back for the title
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ao9mom1s/)**

You could also use `<img>` elements if you want to see the whole image and the height of the container adapt automatically :

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wc9gv4yr/)**

Comment: This isn't working still for me, I need to image to fill the div container it sits in

Comment: What is your web browser ? It works for me, or I don't get what you want

Comment: The text alignment is working perfectly, just still having an issue with the background size not filling out the div.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot in the question, and the desired behaviour ?

Comment: Right, I have managed to fix it by applying the background image size as :

background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

The issue now is the overlay jumps out and is there a way of not having a fixed height on these images?

Comment: So you want to see the whole image and no more ? That would mean to make the container to the height of the image, right ?

Comment: Would that be the best approach to this do you think?

Comment: I think in this case, using `<img>` tags would be easier

Comment: @stackerz See my edit. I provided a demo. I think this is the behaviour you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Add this to CSS:

```
.img1 h2 {
margin-top: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="img1">
    <h2>Family travel...</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img1 {
float: left;
padding: 40px 30px;
width: 25%;
height: 400px;
box-sizing: border-box;
@include background-size(cover);
background-size: contain;
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Most_beautiful_landscape_wallpaper.jpg");
}

.img1 h2 { 
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff; }
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypcxoorw/).

Regards, Milan.